# How can I override example in openapi spec?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I've got the following spec:

```
---
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Players API
  version: 0.0.1-alpha1

paths:
  /players/{id}:
    get:
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlayerWrapper'
components:
  schemas:
    PlayerWrapper:
      type: object
      properties:
        display_name:
          type: string
          example: 76ers
        config:
          description: |
            The configuration of the player.
          example: { spec: { team: 76ers, names: [ 1, 2 ] } }
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Player'
    Player:
      type: object
      properties:
        spec:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasicPlayer'
      additionalProperties: false
    BasicPlayer:
      type: object
      properties:
        team:
          type: string
        names:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Names'
      additionalProperties: false
    Names:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
      example: [ Ben, Joel ]
```

[image]

I did verify on [Swagger](https://apitools.dev/swagger-parser/online/) that it's indeed valid. The question is why I can see `names: [ 1, 2 ]` other than `[ Ben, Joel ]`. When I do remove that `example` thing (`# example: { spec: { team: 76ers, names: [ 1, 2 ] } }`), I can see `Ben, Joel` example:
[image]

Is there a way how I can force override / merge those example? As of now, I feel like my example gets overriden by either of those fields (i.e., either 76ers / [1, 2] or string / [Ben, Joel] but I'd like to get 76ers / [Ben, Joel] instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure in your schemas isn't quite right. The idea is to provide examples on the simple types (strings, int, etc) and the schema will structure it as required.

So dont put the example on config, put it on the nested simple types like this, ie `BasicPlayer` object should have the `example` on team as it's a string:

```yaml
    BasicPlayer:
      type: object
      properties:
        team:
          type: string
          example: '76ers'
        names:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Names'
```

Similar with `PlayerWrapper.config` don't try and give a full object in the example, it gets composed by the member properties. So `team` gets an example, but `Names` example is composed from the child type.

```yaml
    PlayerWrapper:
      type: object
      properties:
        display_name:
          type: string
          example: '76ers'
        config:
          description: |
            The configuration of the player.
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Player'
```

Which should give you the expected example:

[image: Example from swagger]

Here's the full swagger:

```yaml
---
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Players API
  version: 0.0.1-alpha1

paths:
  /players/{id}:
    get:
      parameters: 
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/id'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlayerWrapper'
components:
  parameters:
    id: 
      name: id
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
      description: The id.
  schemas:
    PlayerWrapper:
      type: object
      properties:
        display_name:
          type: string
          example: '76ers'
        config:
          description: |
            The configuration of the player.
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Player'
    Player:
      type: object
      properties:
        spec:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasicPlayer'
      additionalProperties: false
    BasicPlayer:
      type: object
      properties:
        team:
          type: string
          example: '76ers'
        names:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Names'
      additionalProperties: false
    Names:
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
        example: 
          - Ben
          - Joel
```

Note it is possible to override schema examples with an example in the resource definition like this:

```yaml
paths:
  /players/{id}:
    get:
      parameters: 
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/id'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                allOf:
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PlayerWrapper'
              example:
                display_name: 76ers
                config:
                  spec:
                    team: 76ers
                    names:
                      - 'Ben'
                      - 'Joel'
```